# Return Selected Phone Address from iPhone Address Book

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, addressbook

I found a tutorial online that extends that Apple QuickStart Application which is the basic Address Book Application and another that returns the first phone number regardless of what phone number was clicked. I want to display only the selected phone number in the label. The label is called phoneNumber:

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:

(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker

  shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person

                            property:(ABPropertyID)property

                          identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{


ABMutableMultiValueRef phoneMulti = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
NSMutableArray *phones = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneMulti); i++) {
NSString *aPhone = [(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneMulti, i)autorelease];

    [phones addObject:aPhone];
}

NSString *mobileNo = [phones objectAtIndex:0];
self.phoneNumber.text = phones;

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

return NO;

}
```

How do I ensure that the label is the one selected by the user and not just the first array entry(or any other array entry i code in)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you're trying to get the phone number and/or label your user actually selected, you can use this:

```
    - (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
        // ensure user picked a phone property
        if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) {
            ABMultiValueRef phone = ABRecordCopyValue(person, property);
            CFStringRef selectedNumber = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phone, identifier);
            CFStringRef selectedLabel = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phone, identifier);
            // insert code to do something with the values above
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            return NO; } // end if
        else {
            // display an alert or something - handle the error
} } // end else, end method
```

I'm not following your code snippet - not sure what you're using the array for if all you want is the user's selected choice.

Comment: I tried this answer and I can select phone numbers labelled "mobile", "work" and "home". But when "iPhone" is selected, my app crashed. This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12006985/1479411) solved the issue. Hope this will help someone having the same problem as me.