# iPhone sdk: How do I get a count of all the phone numbers in a address book?

Tags: iphone, sdk, addressbook, records

Hi i am developing an app for my QA department. I need to programically get how many phone numbers are there in the entire address book. No user input. Just click a button and then get how many phonenumbers are there in the ENTIRE addressbook.

Comment: I've never seen someone drop their email in to the question. Is this allowed? I don't see why not but I find it odd....

Comment: I agree, odd and probably not compatible with the nature of SO... It should probably be removed from the question

Comment: Email addresses in questions, duplicate user accounts, posting comments as answers.  Not a good start, really.  Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is [ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABGroupRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABGroupCopyArrayOfAllMembers).  See the [AddressBook Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744) and the [QuickContacts](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/QuickContacts/Listings/Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009475-Classes_QuickContactsViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) example for more info on using the AB framework.

Answer (score 0):

from what I can tell from a quick look at `ABMultiValue` in `AddressBook.sqlitedb`, you might get it like this:

1 - sqlite to `/var/mobile/Library/AddressBook/AddressBook.sqlitedb`

2 - `SELECT value FROM ABMultiValue` => into some array

3 - count everything in there that matches `/^[0-9 +]+$/`

look around for some more help doing these steps

Edit:  there's probably also some way to do it with this method:
[How do you get a persons phone number from the address book?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117575/how-do-you-get-a-persons-phone-number-from-the-address-book)