# Get phone number from iPhone address book ERROR in device

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

can any one tell me what is the error in my code . it work fine in the simulator but in the phone and with iTunes make crash. i do not what i shall do to get the error
can any one Help??

```
(BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker 
   shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person 
        property:(ABPropertyID)property 
         identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {
 NSString* name = (NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty );
 //self.firstName.text = name; [name release];
 NSString* name2 = (NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue (person, kABPersonLastNameProperty); 
 NSString* name1= [name stringByAppendingString(angry)" "];
 self.firstName.text = [name1 stringByAppendingString:name2];
 ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person,property);
 NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty,identifier);
 self.PhoneNumber.text = phone;
 [name release]; 
 [phone release];

 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 return NO;
}
```

i made changes as logancautrell advice and use ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier   with ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndexas this the change was in line 11
the old line is

```
 NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty,identifier);
```

the new line is

```
NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty,ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier(phoneProperty,identifier));
```

I test it on my iphone it work good I test it for 3 days and no error or crash BUT when I send it to iTunes they reply

> Your app crashed on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks when we select a contact from the address book.

Comment: At what line does xcode show the crash at?

Comment: Can you post the declarations of the PhoneNumber and firstName properties?

Comment: PhoneNumber and firstName Are lables

Comment: the crash done when select a phone number

Comment: Check the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117575/how-do-you-get-a-persons-phone-number-from-the-address-book

Answer (score 1):

In the docs for ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex:

```
Raises an exception when out of bounds
```

So it is possible that the ABMultiValueIdentifier does not exist in that particular ABRecordRef. Try using ABMultiValueGetIndexForIdentifier an make sure the CFIndex returned is valid before doing the copy.

Comment: i do as advice i use 'ABMultiValueIdentifier' but still error please have  a lock to the post agian i update it

Comment: Like your advice, it is better to make sure that CFIndex returned is a  valid CFIndex. But in this case, how I could make sure this CFIndex is valid or not. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

**Edit:** this is wrong. Methods seemed like assessor methods to me, faulty to assume autorelease was in order.

> Because you release objects which you did not allocate:
>
> ```
> [name release]; 
> [phone release];
> ```

Comment: The op owns those items. Note the function name: `ABRecordCopyValue()` then see the docs at *Performance > Memory Management for Core Foundation > Ownership Policy > The Create Rule*.

Comment: name and phone definitely DO need to be released, as ABRecordCopyValue will allocate new copies.  In fact, name2 should be released as well.