# Get Address and Phone Numbers from Contact?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, contacts

In my app I need to get a bunch of contact details, I can successfully get things like first and last name like so:

```
NSString *firstName = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

However I can't get any phone numbers of address details like this, any help in doing would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A person has only one name, but might have multiple phone numbers. You need to get all known phones, like this:

```
ABMultiValueRef allPhones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
```

Then you can look for a specific number (home, work, mobile, etc.) inside the `ABMultiValueRef`. Same goes for the address.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1252995/335858) is a good answer demonstrating the technique; it's pre-ARC, so naturally you will need to add `__bridge` to the casts.