# Fetch Name AND Number contact list Address Book

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook, abaddressbook

I'm trying to NSLog name and number from my contact in Address Book.
I succeed to log the name, but I don't succeed to solve the problem with number.

Here is my code :

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
if (addressBook != NULL) {
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
        if (granted) {
            CFArrayRef allNames = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

            if (allNames != NULL) {
                NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray array];
                for (int i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(allNames); i++) {
                    ABRecordRef group = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allNames, i);
                    CFStringRef name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(group);
                    [names addObject:(__bridge NSString *)name];
                    CFRelease(name);
                }


                NSLog(@"names = %@", names);
                CFRelease(allNames);
            }
        }
        CFRelease(addressBook);
    });
}
```

Maybe I have to create NSDictionnary ? I don't know how to solve it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a Phone Number from an Address Book Contact (iphone sdk)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/286207/how-to-get-a-phone-number-from-an-address-book-contact-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phone numbers are a `ABMultiValueRef`:

```
ABMultiValueRef phones = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
if (phones != NULL) {
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); index++) {
        NSString *phone = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, index));
        NSString *label = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, index));  // either kABHomeLabel or kABPersonPhoneMainLabel or ...
        // do something with `phone` and `label`
    }
    CFRelease(phones);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use `ABRecordCopyValue(group, kABPersonPhoneProperty)` which returns `ABMultiValueRef`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/286281/171089 for more.